# Regex to validate string "Username <Email_ID>"

Tags: java, regex, validation

In my web application, I am using user info in the form of

> `Username <Email_ID>`

For example

```
Firstname Lastname<abc@xyz.com> is a valid input
```

Now I want to validate this whether User has entered something in this pattern only. I know regex about validating just email id but I am not able to get a regex for this expression.

Is there any other way possible to validate this info?

Comment: Sounds rather unclear. Try `^\S+\s<EMAIL_REGEX_HERE>$` (double the backslashes in the Java string pattern and you may omit `^` and `$` if `Matcher#matches` is used).

Comment: Is Email_ID a variable placeholder? I guess so. Are these valid email addresses (that may be tedious to parse). Are there other angle brackets in the text you receive? Is Username a fixed token, or could it be "Joe" for one user and "Sarah" for another? Please add some detail. Thanks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Actually my main question was this: using regex for parsing a *very huge* file is reasonable? that's it.

Comment: @stack: Do not use a regex to parse 700MB XML file. Use an XML parser/XSLT, other XML tools. Or write your own parser for a custom log format, it is not that difficult. Inside, you may use any amount of regexps you wish.

Comment: @ChiragKawariya where is the email regex you say working for you?
Please share.